# Maven exclude/remove test dependency defined in parent POM

Tags: java, maven, logback, slf4j

This is similar to [Exclude dependency in child pom inherited from parent pom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65288138), except that it has to do with `test` vs `compile` scopes.

I have a parent POM that includes the `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` dependency so that all descendant projects will be using SLF4J for the logging API. Then, so that all projects can have some logging for unit tests (regardless of which SLF4J implementation they use in the main, that is non-test, part of the project), I include SLF4J Simple, but only in the `test` scope:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

(*I understand the view that parent POMs should not declare dependencies and only use dependency management. While I don't disagree in general, configuring tests is a different story. I don't want every single subproject to have to declare JUnit, Hamcrest, Hamcrest Optional, Mockito, Simple Logging, etc. The testing framework should be uniform across all our projects without a huge amount of ceremony just to set up a project.*)

This works fine until one project `Foo` wants to use Logback as the SLF4J implementation.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

That works fine for the `Foo` application itself, but now for the `Foo` tests, there are suddenly two competing SLF4J implementations: Logback and SLF4J simple. This presents a bindings conflict:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J: Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@363ee3a2]
SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider@4690b489]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@363ee3a2]
```

I need to do one of the following:

- In the POM where I bring in the `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` dependency, I need to *exclude* the `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple` from the parent POM. (This is the preferred solution.)
- In the POM where I bring in the `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` dependency, I need to specify that `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` is for all scopes *except* the `test` scope (so as not to conflict with `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple`).

I don't readily see how to do either of these. Any ideas?

One suggestion was to redeclare `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple` with `<scope>provided</scope>`. Thus `pom.xml` for project `Foo` would look like this:

```xml
…
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
…
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work. SLF4J still sees two SLF4J providers on the classpath, and is showing the message seen above. A scope of `provided` simply keeps the dependency from being included transitively in other projects; it doesn't seem to remove it from the classpath of the current project.

Comment: I do believe, it is not a good idea to specify dependencies in parent poms, at first glance it looks attractive, however as soon as you started overriding those dependencies your project turns into mess. BTW, you may specify scope=`provided` for that dependency in child module in order to ban it

Comment: You can solve this (as the referred question) with profiles.

Comment: Define the dependencies you need in your parent pom via dependencyManagement instead and define there the exclusions you really need. But I would recommend not to use a parent pom for such purposes better define you own so called BOM (a pom which contains only a dependencyManagement) as many frameworks do (spring boot, etc.)

Comment: @xerx593 Never use profiles for dependencies.

Comment: "I do believe, it is not a good idea to specify dependencies in parent poms …" I don't disagree, except for test configuration; see my updated question. "[Y]ou may specify scope=`provided` for that dependency in child module …" No, unfortunately that still isn't working. SLF4J still sees two SLF4J providers on the classpath. `provided` simply keeps it from being included transitively in other projects; it doesn't seem to remove it from the classpath of the current project.

Comment: "… better define you own so called BOM …" I am well acquainted with a build-of-materials POM, but for configuring the _test framework_ across our projects, it works better to actually declare the dependencies in the parent POM.

Comment: What about the other option: how could I declare `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` for all scopes _except_ `test` scope?

Comment: @GarretWilson sorry, I have completely forgotten that `test` scope is "special", for you particular case it is possible to take advantage of [classpathDependencyExcludes config option](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#classpathDependencyExcludes)

Comment: Andrey I had seen this Surefire plugin exclusion. But how does that help with transitive dependency references? So if MyApp extends from MyRoot, which declares `slf4j-simple` in `test` scope; but then has a dependency on `BaseApp` which has `logback-classic` as a dependency, even if `BaseApp` excludes `slf4j-simple` from the Surefire plugin, that will have no effect on `MyApp`, and `MyApp` will wind up with both `slf4j-simple` and `logback-classic` on the classpath. On the other hand, how could `BaseApp` ever remove something from `MyApp`'s inheritance? I'll need to think more about this …

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to build the Cathedral using wrong tools and instead of Cathedral you are getting pagan temple :)

1. technically, it is possible to override classpath/module dependencies imposed by parent pom by defining `system` scope, [something like](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/so73747106/tree/system_scope_poc):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../dummy.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

however, I wouldn't recommend to do that

2. another option is to take advantage of [classpathDependencyExcludes config option](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#classpathDependencyExcludes) of surefire plugin, [something like](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/so73747106/tree/classpathDependencyExcludes):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>org.slf4j:slf4j-simple</classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

3. If particular parent does not suit child's needs, child may adopt another parent :) There is no strict requirement that the aggregator pom must be the parent pom
4. the real problem is unlike [modern build tools](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) maven does not distinguish `test compile` and `test runtime` scopes, however it is possible to [emulate such behaviour](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/so73747106/tree/master)

```
<properties>
    <surefire.runtime>${project.build.directory}/surefire-runtime/slf4j-simple-2.0.1.jar</surefire.runtime>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-surefire-runtime</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-runtime/</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <additionalClasspathElements>${surefire.runtime}</additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

yep, too many words there, but in my opinion that is only correct configuration for `test runtime` dependencies, m.b. it worth to submit a corresponding PR to surefire project - I believe that needs to write about 10 LoC to avoid `maven-dependency-plugin` configuration and able to configure `test runtime` in the following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.1</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```